# Textbox is not keeping values or losing values after post back on telerik textbox which are inserted or appended via Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0, textbox, telerik

I am having a problem with my radTextBox values, the values inserted via JavaScript is being removed after the post back happens but the values inserted through c# are there. I am taking values from radgrid and inserting them into textbox.

The scenario:

1: insert or append values via JavaScript
2: insert or append values via c# method which triggers postback

## Html Code for Textbox:

```
<telerik:RadTextBox ID="rtxtToEmail" runat="server" Width="300px" Skin="Office2007"
                            TextMode="MultiLine" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
                        </telerik:RadTextBox>
```

## Html Code for Button that calls JavaScript function:

```
<telerik:RadButton ID="rdbtnTo" runat="server" Skin="Office2007" Width="68px" Text="Selected" OnClientClicked="ToSelected" AutoPostBack="false">
                    </telerik:RadButton>
```

## Javascript Code:

```
function ToSelected(sender, args) {
                         var grid = $find("<%=rgWOAssignedType.ClientID %>");
                        var DataItem = grid.get_masterTableView().get_dataItems()[grid._selectedIndexes];
                        var keyValues = DataItem.getDataKeyValue("Email");
                        //alert(keyValues); return false;

                        if (keyValues != "") {
                            document.getElementById("<%= rtxtToEmail.ClientID %>").value +=
                             keyValues + ";"
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
```

## C# Code on button click event which triggers the post back:

```
protected void rbtnToClient_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                #region Fill To CLient Email

                if (ViewState["ClientEmail"] != null)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ViewState["ClientEmail"].ToString()))
                    {
                        rtxtToEmail.Text += ViewState["ClientEmail"].ToString() + ";";
                    }
                }

                #endregion
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                try { throw new WTLIB.WTException(ex); }
                catch (WTLIB.WTException eX) { eX.WriteToEventLog(); eX.MessageError(Page); }
            }
        }
```

Comment: chances are there is a javascript API for the telerik controls that you are not using, which will probably make anything you try to do not work.

Comment: Solved using server side event on button click and removed the javascript code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a server control, you must also use the provided [javascript API](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/input-client-side-basics.html) or the control will not work correctly.

> get_textBoxValue(), set_textBoxValue()
>   string
>   Gets or sets the value the user input text. It is not assigned as the value of the input control if it contains an error.